# Android app with WebView of AR ( Augmented Reality ) Website Android Studio + kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, webview, augmented-reality

I have android application which contains a webview of one website with AR facility.

But I am facing an issue that normal webview of android doesn't allow to open AR mode and tried to open with intent then it will redirect to google sceneform link.

I want to add button in AR mode with website. That button can take screenshot of AR mode.

I have taken all the permissions. camera, AR.
Installed all of the plugins correctly still can't get succeed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to run one website in a webView which has AR mode but, android webView is not strong enough to support AR mode so I am opening this url with intent. Now I want to take screenshot in AR mode. Intent url open with chrome tab by default so I have no controll over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Consider that which technology is your webAR experience using ?! maybe it is webXR. and as you understood, webXR is [not supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=webxr) in android web view ! so if you really want to see AR in webview, you may reconsider which webAR you are using ( try [AR.js](https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/#:%7E:text=on%20the%20Web-,AR.,based%20AR%20and%20Marker%20tracking.) or [mind-AR](https://hiukim.github.io/mind-ar-js-doc/#:%7E:text=MindAR%20is%20an%20opensource%20web,0.) or [8thWall](https://www.8thwall.com/)(paid) or etc. )
But Consider that webXR is almost fully supported by chrome browser on android. so if you open that website on chrome browser, it may run without any problems. If you still have questions, please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your solution is 100% true. Even I have applied this solution in my application but it has drawback that I can't control that WebAR open by chrome browser. That is the real situation I facing right now.